# Why is Spring Data MongoDB insert/save operation not returning the ObjectId

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, spring-data-mongodb

I have tried this several ways (U can assume my MongoConfiguration is Correct)

Using `implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb:2.5.3'`

**My Class**

```kotlin
@Document(collection = "address")
class Address {
    @Id
    var id: String? = null
    var label: String? = null
    var number: String? = null
    var street: String? = null
    ...
```

**My Repository**

```kotlin
@Repository
interface AddressRepository : MongoRepository<Address, String> {
    fun findByLabel(label: String): Address
}
```

**in My @RestController** I call the save (or insert)

```kotlin
val savedAddress = addressRepository.insert(address)
```

According to `Gradle: org.springframework.data:spring-data-mongodb:3.1.6` as well as `Gradle: org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:2.4.6` Docs

> **Returns:** the saved entity; will never be null.

However It does create a record! I inspected the result by using Compass

But it only echoes the address content I used to create it! **witout the ID**
If I would query the record e.g.

```kotlin
returnedAddress= savedAddress.label?.let { addressRepository.findByLabel(it) }!!
```

I get the rocord returned WITH the Id!
This Behavior I detected some time now and it is not always possible to locate the correct record again if the Id is the only Unique key in the collection!

**Is there a Mistake?**, configuration or any other way I can get the ObjectId / _id emmitted properly

**Note:** `<S extends T> S save(S entity)` calls insert when the entity record is new

Comment: *However It does create a record*, *I get the rocord returned WITH the Id* Unclear what you are asking. *it only echoes the address content I used to create it! witout the ID* is the the result in Compass or somewhere else?

Comment: It is simple if I create a record with label and number as input the record gets created, the Object Id is made BUT the function insert / save returns only the label and number values I use to create the record with WITHOUT returning the ObjectID also

Comment: try `repository.save()`

Comment: @sidgate If you read my code/post that is Exactly what I am doing
If you know Spring, you would know that Save calls Instert if new record, witch it is.

Comment: you are calling `insert` method above. I suggested to instead call `save` method. try and let know